# How to restore asp.net identity tables after deleting them manually?

Tags: asp.net-core

I added identity to my context class using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore and that created all my aspnetroles, aspnetuserlogins,... tables. However, I wanted to start over and deleted those tables from my database. Now I cannot seem to get them back. Any idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I usually delete the database table and delete the Migrations folder.Then I  run the`Add-Migration migrationname` command and  then  run the `Update-Database` command. Then I can get them back.